# Can I configure Vite to rewrite a file path when reading a file from disk?

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project (although I suspect that SvelteKit is irrelevant to this issue). Let's imagine it has the following folder structure:

```
vite.config.ts
/src
    /routes
        +server.ts
/external
    somefile.txt
```

I want `/src/routes/+server.ts` to read and process the contents of `/external/somefile.txt`.

I added an alias to my `vite.config.ts`:

```json
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $external: 'external'
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected with JS imports, but does not work with if I do, say:

```js
readFile('$external/somefile.txt')
```

Is there a way (either using `config.resolve.alias` or some other preprocessor approach) to rewrite the file path?

Comment: Why not import?

Comment: @H.B. I might be missing something very obvious here - can get the contents of a file as a string using `import`?

Answer (score 0):

> can you get the contents of a file as a string using `import`?

Yes, you can. One can do just about anything via imports using plugins.

By default, Vite will import various asset types as URLs, but you can add query suffixes to change this. If you want to read the contents, you can add the [`?raw` query](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string).

```js
import somefileContent from '$external/somefile.txt?raw';
```

You can of course also use a dynamic import if you want to defer this.